# how to prove the following equation monotonically decreases with m.

Tags: functions, derivatives

$$l = \frac{t_{iL}(t_{iH} - m\tau)\rho_H - t_{iH}(t_{iL} - m\tau)\rho_L}{m[(t_{iL} - m\tau)\rho_L + (t_{iH} - m\tau)\rho_H]}$$

where $t_{iL}$, $t_{iH}$,$m$, $\tau$, $\rho_H$, $\rho_L$ are greater than 0.

$\rho_H \geq \rho_L$

Prove $\frac{dl}{dm} < 0$. Thank you.

Comment: You need $$ instead of $ around the formula to get it to a readable size!

Comment: No not around every bit of math, because $$ also puts it on a line of its own!

Comment: A lot of unfashionable indices!

Comment: Relable your indices, say $(\alpha, \beta,..)$ and use quotient rule to show the derivative is negative.

Comment: Is $t_{iH}\ge t_{iL}$? If so, the result would seem to be false. Eg take $\rho_H=\rho_L$ Also can we assume $m\tau<t_{iL}+t_{iH}$. If not there is a discontinuity (and sign flip) at $m\tau=t_{iL}+t_{iH}$ (which might not affect the sign of the derivative, but might be physically implausible)

Answer (score 0):

**Case 1**. If $\rho_H=\rho_L$, then $$\ell(m)=\frac{(t_{iH}-t_{iL})\tau}{t_{iH}+t_{iL}-2m\tau}$$

[image]

If $t_{iH}>t_{iL}$ (which seems plausible if H=high, L=low) then for small $m$ $\ell(m)$ is positive. It increases until $m$ reaches $(t_{iH}+t_{iL})/2\tau$, when it flips sign, and then continues to increase, so the derivative is positive. Similarly, if $t_{iH}<t_{iL}$, then the derivative is negative. If it is zero, the derivative is zero.

The plot above illustrates the case with negative derivative.

**Case 2**. Otherwise we can put

$$\lambda=\frac{t_{iL}t_{iH}(\rho_H-\rho_L)}{t_{iL}\rho_{iL}+t_{iH}\rho_{iH}}>0$$ and$$h=\frac{(t_{iH}\rho_L-t_{iL}\rho_H)\tau}{t_{iL}t_{iH}(\rho_H-\rho_L)}\hspace{1cm}k=\frac{\tau(\rho_H+\rho_L)}{t_{iL}\rho_{iL}+t_{iH}\rho_{iH}}>0$$ to give

$$\ell(m)=\lambda\ \frac{1+hm}{m(1-km)}$$

[image]

If $h<0$, ie $t_{iH}<t_{iL}$ then $h<0$ then the derivative is negative provided $k\le|h|$ (but of course $\ell(m)$ has a sign flip and discontinuity at $m=1/k$ (which is not relevant if $k<0$) [The $h=1,k=0.5$ is shown in the plot immediately above.]

[image]

If $k>|h|$ then it is decreasing up to $m=1/k$, then increasing. The plot immediately above shows the case $h=1,k=2$.

---

I suspect only some of these cases are of interest, but I had no response to my question in comments for 2 days, so I have put up my answer and moved on!

Incidentally, I strongly endorse @MohammadRiazi-Kermani's comment - it would be much easier to understand and answer your question if you changed all the variables to much simpler names (eg $a,b,c,...$). Please don't change them now, but another time ...